# Adding WKWebView Programmatically

Tags: ios, wkwebview, activity-indicator

I am a beginner in iOS development and I have been having difficulty adding WKWebview with code. I intend to make it full width too but I get an empty screen.

```
var webView = WKWebView()
var activityIndicatorView: ActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
     //show Activity Indicator
    self.activityIndicatorView = ActivityIndicatorView(title: "Loading content...", center: self.view.center)
    self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating();
    self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicatorView.getViewActivityIndicator())self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicatorView.getViewActivityIndicator())
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let urlString = "http://www.youtube.com";
    let request = URLRequest(url:URL(string: urlString)!)
    self.webView.load(request)
     self.view = webView
}
```

Comment: Add the constraints. Or give it a frame.

Comment: you should add indicator after assign `self.view = webview` or add indicator view in side webView.

when you assign webview to self.view at that time self.view is replaced by webview and webview has no activityIndicatorView

Answer (score 2):

```
let webview = WKWebView()
    webview.frame  = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
    webview.load(URLRequest(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension:"html", subdirectory: "subdirectories")! as URL) as URLRequest)
    self.view.addSubview(webview)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    let wv = WKWebView()
    wv.uiDelegate = self
    wv.navigationDelegate = self
    wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return wv
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(webView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a webView with zero frame, that's why it's not showing.

Change `webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)` to this:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
```

To display the activity indicator while loading the page, you need to implement `WKNavigationDelegate` delegate. Update your code to this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView = WKWebView()
    var activityIndicatorView: ActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
         //show Activity Indicator
        self.activityIndicatorView = ActivityIndicatorView(title: "Loading content...", center: self.view.center)
        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating();
        self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicatorView.getViewActivityIndicator())self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicatorView.getViewActivityIndicator())
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let urlString = "http://www.youtube.com";
        let request = URLRequest(url:URL(string: urlString)!)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self // Add this line!
        self.webView.load(request)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.view = webView
        // Hide activity indicator here
    }
}
```

Comment: your code works but it covers my activity indicator which I am adding as a subview too

Comment: @bennycodest What's your activity indicator's frame? Please share its code. when are you hiding it?

Comment: @bennycodest I've updated the answer. Notice that I've added `WKNavigationDelegate` to the class declaration and `navigationDelegate` to `viewDidLoad`